# Longevity Mode for Dell Latitude 7490

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, battery, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude E7490, and I want to turn on some kind of battery conservation mode. In particular, if the battery is, say, at 100% and I unplug it for a few mins, and the charge drops to 95%, I don't want it to charge back up to 100% when I plug it back in.

It appears that dell has a "longevity mode" for this, from a utility called "Dell QuickSet". However, this doesn't appear to be available for my model -- and on the Dell website, the screenshot is from XP, which isn't encouraging!

Such an application is very useful -- I had a Lenovo laptop prior to this, and it would only charge up to 60%, and not charge if above 50%, when "conservation mode" was on. I used this almost the whole time, as most of the time I Have my laptop on AC power. However, sometimes I go on quite long journeys, and it's helpful not to have to use the power cable, so I still want a long lasting battery

Comment: Any thoughts, anyone? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find revelant configuration option in the System Setup (press F2 after starting the laptop).

In *Power Management* screen there should be a section titled *Primary Battery Charge Configuration*. There you’ll probably want to choose *Primarily AC use* or *Custom*.

---

This can also be done via *Dell Command | Power Manager*, which is a Dell app that can be downloaded [directly](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/uk/en/ukbsdt1/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/software-and-downloads/dell-power-manager) or from the [Windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/p/dell-power-manager/9pd11rq8qc9k). This allows the above settings to be changed without restarting the machine; further settings are also available.

Comment: That's superb, thank you so much! Upon searching for more details for what "primary battery charge" actually does, I found that there's actually a thing called "Dell Command | Power Manager" which one can install (eg from the Windows store). This means that I can change exactly the settings you describe, but without having to load System Setup. I just edited your answer to add these links, hope that's ok! (Ok, the edit is still in peer review)